# Как добраться до значения в строке JSON JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

У меня есть переменная item. Она содержит вот такой комплект котировок:

```
{"symbol":"EURUSD","bid":1.14358,"ask":1.14366,"price":1.14362}
{"symbol":"GBPUSD","bid":1.30386,"ask":1.30403,"price":1.30395}
{"symbol":"USDJPY","bid":109.886,"ask":109.901,"price":109.8935}
{"symbol":"USDCAD","bid":1.31142,"ask":1.31157,"price":1.31149}
{"symbol":"EURGBP","bid":0.8769,"ask":0.87726,"price":0.87708}
{"symbol":"USDCHF","bid":0.99788,"ask":0.99808,"price":0.99798}
{"symbol":"AUDUSD","bid":0.72232,"ask":0.72238,"price":0.72235}
{"symbol":"NZDUSD","bid":0.68867,"ask":0.68873,"price":0.6887}
{"symbol":"GBPJPY","bid":143.248,"ask":143.31,"price":143.279}
{"symbol":"USDMXN","bid":19.1027,"ask":19.1047,"price":19.1037}
{"symbol":"USDRUB","bid":65.5142,"ask":65.6183,"price":65.5662}
{"symbol":"USDZAR","bid":13.4204,"ask":13.4277,"price":13.424}
{"symbol":"BTCUSD","bid":3446.2,"ask":3446.2,"price":3446.2}
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как я могу добраться до конкретного символа строки?
Например, мне нужно дальше проверить:

```
if(item.symbol == 'EURUSD'){
 //....
}
```

Но у меня не получается обратиться к конкретной строке, например:
item[0].symbol, как буд-то все эти 13 строк и есть item[0]

Comment: Так это ж просто набор объектов. При чем без имени. А надо массив. Ну что-то вроде `let array = [{..}, {..}, {..}...]`, и уже тогда `array[i].symbol === value`. Или я не допонял чего-то...

Answer (score 0):

В общем, вот. Работает всё.

```js
let array = [{"symbol":"EURUSD","bid":1.14358,"ask":1.14366,"price":1.14362},
{"symbol":"GBPUSD","bid":1.30386,"ask":1.30403,"price":1.30395},
{"symbol":"USDJPY","bid":109.886,"ask":109.901,"price":109.8935},
{"symbol":"USDCAD","bid":1.31142,"ask":1.31157,"price":1.31149},
{"symbol":"EURGBP","bid":0.8769,"ask":0.87726,"price":0.87708},
{"symbol":"USDCHF","bid":0.99788,"ask":0.99808,"price":0.99798},
{"symbol":"AUDUSD","bid":0.72232,"ask":0.72238,"price":0.72235},
{"symbol":"NZDUSD","bid":0.68867,"ask":0.68873,"price":0.6887},
{"symbol":"GBPJPY","bid":143.248,"ask":143.31,"price":143.279},
{"symbol":"USDMXN","bid":19.1027,"ask":19.1047,"price":19.1037},
{"symbol":"USDRUB","bid":65.5142,"ask":65.6183,"price":65.5662},
{"symbol":"USDZAR","bid":13.4204,"ask":13.4277,"price":13.424},
{"symbol":"BTCUSD","bid":3446.2,"ask":3446.2,"price":3446.2}];

array.forEach((item) => {
  console.log(item.symbol);
});
```